# Datetimepicker disappear in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using Bootstrap Datetimepicker for setting `start_at` and `end_at` time in my Rails app.

If you set `end_at` future time, of course you can set and edit, but if you edit the event you set before and already expired because of `end_at`, the time disapper in view.

In my DB, of course I can have correct `end_at` time, but not view.

How can I put correct time (past time) in my view?

```
$('#tickets .datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm',
    showClose:true,                    
    useCurrent:false,
    minDate: d,
    maxDate: y,
    stepping: 15,
    // sideBySide:true
});

$("#tickets .datetimepicker3").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    $('.datetimepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);                    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the date on page load in java script from rails.

```
setdate('#{object.end_date}'})

funtione setdate(end_date){    
$('#tickets .datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
     format: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm',
     showClose:true,                    
     useCurrent:false,
     minDate: d,
     maxDate: moment(end_date,'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm'),
     stepping: 15,
     // sideBySide:true
 });
}
```

you can use moment() of datetimepicker.